# VS 2022 Preview always crashing after adding a new file

Tags: tfs, crash, visual-studio-2022

When I try to add a new file to a project, the VS 2022 Preview always crashes. All information I can found in Event Log is the following:

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 17.0.31423.177, time
> stamp: 0xac8b0d94 Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version:
> 10.0.19041.1023, time stamp: 0x7977b9de Exception code: 0xc0000374 Fault offset: 0x00000000000ff199 Faulting process id: 0x76a4 Faulting
> application start time: 0x01d76db5c416e4bc Faulting application path:
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe Faulting module path:
> C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll Report Id:
> 8f2ea6f1-6457-4367-9b8f-454e41a37167 Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Additional information:

- the project is a .NET Framework project
- the project is under TFS on-premise
- it is under a private workspace

We can add new files without any problem to this project using VS 2019 Professional. When I open this solution with VS 2022 Preview - it loads. It compiles, everything is ok. But when I try to add a new file to the project, after a short time it crashes. Always.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue that I can't track down, but it's having to do with adding another project to a blazor wasm project. If Ii only have the blazor prj, all is good, but the minute i add a console app or something else, the solution gets "corrupted" and won't compile and shows blank folders with ** in front of them. I've had to deleted the other apps, deleted the bin and obj folders, and just open the blazor app by itself.

I'm on .net 6/vs 2022 preview. Here are my versions:

```
3.1.411 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.100-preview.6.21355.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

--Visual Studio--

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview
Version 17.0.0 Preview 2.1
VisualStudio.17.Preview/17.0.0-pre.2.1+31521.260
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Community

.NET Core Debugging with WSL 2   1.0
.NET Core Debugging with WSL 2

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   17.0.303.37752
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   17.0.303.37752
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.0.303.37752
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.0.303.37752
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

C# Tools   4.0.0-2.21362.3+5f7ddf6f02d40036fdbf823cd9910027da277acd
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
Fabric Diagnostic Events

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   17.0
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.134+45632ee938.RR
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.2
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

NuGet Package Manager   6.0.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.0.0.2135615+c94df2e3bebc72c937da0389b22d730b5ea7b19b
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62107.02200
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript Tools   17.0.0701.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.0.0-2.21362.3+5f7ddf6f02d40036fdbf823cd9910027da277acd
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.0.0-beta.21352.5+3af67cd8ffd73b2dc443e1e24dc0cf28f7e1c608
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions   1.0
View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, after a new update the bug disappeared.